# Responsive web page layout containing datagrid

Tags: html, css, layout, web

I've been trying to find how to achieve a layout as shown in image below, but failing to find this exact layout. [image]

I'm trying to achieve a responsive layout that contains a datagrid (ui-grid) in it's content panel. When the window resizes, the grid resizes accordingly, i.e. the grid's scrollbar changes, while no scrollbar is wanted on the actual content panel the datagrid sits within - is this possible? It's almost like a holy grail layout, just I don't want the content div scrollable, just the datagrid itself. I've been trying with Flexbox, but have been unsuccessful - any great links would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Post the code you've tried please.

Comment: I've done away from having the datagrid contain the full div, but rather have the containing div just scroll on overflow - working great, so not to worry.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at this from a user-experience viewpoint. Imagine you have this working and you are swiping down a scrollable table on a mobile device. You can't scroll up or down through the rest of the email until you either reach the top or bottom. The result, whether it's scrollable or not, is the same. It seems like a "holy grail" but in practice it's sort of a net-zero. (How many embedded maps have you had take over your mobile screen because you can't swipe away from it, only within it?)

What you want to do can be achieved on some email clients with an **overflow: scroll** on the container, but not reliably on many.

Comment: Good point, and thank you for your feedback. So would you suggest that the datagrid shouldn't be made scrollable, but rather the container DIV have the scrollability? I would like the buttons to be always visible, so I guess those could just be in a div of their own.